# How to detect if a user has typed an integer on their keyboard in pygame?

Tags: python

I am making a Calculator with Pygame and I want to check if the user has pressed a key which is an integer. If the key is an integer like 1 or 2 then blit the number onto the screen.
I have tried but many times but failed

Here's my code

```
import pygame, math

pygame.init()
screen_width = 1200
screen_height = 500
gameWindow = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Calculator')
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
grey = (128, 128, 128)
font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 40)
fps = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def text_screen(text, color, x, y):
     screen_text = font.render(text, True, color)
     gameWindow.blit(screen_text, [x ,y])

def welcome_screen(run):
    clock.tick(fps) 
    gameWindow.fill(grey)
    while not run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                 run = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == # Code to check whether the key is integer or not:
                     pass
        pygame.display.update()

def gameLoop(run):
    clock.tick(fps)
    gameWindow.fill(grey)
    while not run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = True
        pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    welcome_screen(False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert the keycode to it's representing character, then check if it is a digit with isdigit().

```py
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if pygame.key.name(event.key).isdigit():
        pass # Do stuff
```

Comment: How can I store the number somewhere. Like when the user presses a key like 1 or 2. Then If I want to show it in the screen how can I?

Comment: `key = pygame.key.name(event.key)
if key.isdigit():
    text_screen(key, (0, 0, 0), 0, 0)`
This will not overwrite the last key tho, so you will need to figure out a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `keyboard` module and bind the key press event to a function:

```
import keyboard  # using module keyboard

def myonkeypress(event):
    if event.name.isnumeric() :
       print('User pressed numeric key')

# hook event handler
keyboard.on_press(myonkeypress)
```

Comment: Is this module built-in or I have to install it with pip?

Comment: You'll have to install it.

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with pygame, but there is a Python built-in function that may help you: `isinstance()`. (Docs: https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#isinstance)

It checks if a given object is `str`, `int` etc. Returns `True` or `False`. It works like this:

```py
x = 5
if isinstance(x, int):
    do_this()
```

That said, there is a catch: although I have never used pygame, I read its docs (http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html). It states the following:

> The integers for key constants differ between pygame 1 and 2. Always use key constants (K_a) rather than integers directly (97) so that your key handling code works well on both pygame 1 and pygame 2.

So I guess you'd better use something different from `isinstance()`. Something like:

```py
[...]
def welcome_screen(run):
    clock.tick(fps) 
    gameWindow.fill(grey)
    while not run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                 run = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key in [pygame.K_1, pygame.K_2]:
                     pass
        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to store the number in a variable or something?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the numeric key, I suggest to check first, if no modifying key was pressed. For example, if we press `SHIFT` + `1`, depending on your keyboard, you probably will get an exclamation mark (`!`), not the actual digit of `1`.

In order to do this, and also get the integer value of the pressed key, we can do the following:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    # Check if no modifier keys are pressed (for example: SHIFT):
    if event.mod == pygame.KMOD_NONE:
        # event.key returns the ASCII code of the key, we can find out if it is numeric by checking if
        # the ASCII value of the key is between the ASCII value of '0' and '9'
        if pygame.K_0 <= event.key <= pygame.K_9:
            # Store the pressed key into a variable
            pressed_digit = event.key - pygame.K_0
            # Do something with it
            print(f'Key pressed: {pressed_digit}')
```